# Unit test with Mockito using HttpURLConnection

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I know this has been asked before, I try to follow but it's still not working for me.
I have to do this in Mockito.
My knowledge of Mockito is a rookie.

When I executed I'm getting a Failure Trace

```
    org.mockito.exception.misusing.NullInsteadOfMockException:
```

Not sure what I'm missing and how to fix it.  I have searched over few days now and I'm not getting any luck.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code in Spring Boot 2 making external call with HTTPUrlConnection.
It's working fine.

```
@Component
public class GetData {
   @Value("{lookupUrl}
   private String url;

public StringBuilder getData(String str) {
    String httpUrl = url + str;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL link = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readline()) != null {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
        conn.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.getStatckTrace();
    }
    return sb;
}
```

}

// Here is my unit test

```
public class DataTest {
   @Spy
   GetData getdata;

   @Mock
   HttpURLConnection connection;

   @Test
   public void getDataTest() {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append("test data");
      try{
          doReturn(connection).when(getdata).getTheData(any());  //this is where error raised
          URL url = new URL("http://anyhost.com");
          sb = getdata.getTheData(url.toString());
          doReturn(sb).when(connection).getInputStream();
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
          e.getStatckTrace();
      }
      assertTrue(sb.length() > 1);
  }
```

}

Comment: doReturn(connection).when(getdata).getTheData(any()); // how can this return connection, when getData is supposed to return StringBuilder

Comment: To get past that error you need to init the mock `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` on the test class for junit 4 or `@ExtendWith` for junit 5. But, your class is untestable with mockito. You have no way to access and set the connection to the mock. Maybe read on [testing seams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327724/what-is-the-difference-between-a-seam-and-a-mock)

Answer (score 0):

doReturn(connection).when(getdata).getTheData(any());

how can you make it return connection, when getData is supposed to return StringBuilder.

Can you make an attempt to ask questions properly??
This code works

```
doReturn(sb).when(getdata).getData(any());  //this is where error raised
URL url = new URL("http://anyhost.com");
StringBuilder response = getdata.getData(url.toString());
```

Assuming that you are initializing mocks properly via init or annotations